# Windows domain changed cause sql2005 login fail

Tags: sql-server, windows, dns

My company change the domain from abc to xyz and now i can't log into my local sql2005 via Windows login nor sql login.

both login gave me this error: An error has occured while establishing a connection to the server. blah blah blah...Sql server does not allow remote connection. Error:26  - Error locating Server/Instance specified.

i check the server instance is running. i can understand the windows login fail but how can sql login fail as well? does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It's weird but i find the solution. I select the database that i want to connect to which is the same instance on the login screen then using the sql authentication. i was able to login in. It turn out the my work station was renamed. that's why it can't find the server instance.

Answer (score 0):

What server name are you using? If you're using anything other than (local), localhost, or . - then you probably need to change the server to NEWDOMAIN\HOSTNAME or hostname.newdomain.com.